# Синтез речи на сайте с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть текст на русском и арабском, хочу подключить синтез речи на прямую в HTML или через JS, можете дайте ссылку на туториал (не на буржуйском ◕‿◕) или если это пустяк объясните пожалуйста как это реализовать.

Comment: https://antonz.ru/speech-api/

Comment: @AlexZaslavskis спасибо большое за помощь.

Comment: Плюсани комент пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Автор [этой](https://antonz.ru/speech-api/) статьи предлагает такой метод :

```js
function speak(text) {
  const message = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  message.lang = "ru-RU";
  message.text = text;
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(message);
}

const btnSpeak = document.querySelector("#speak");
const txtMessage = document.querySelector("#message");

btnSpeak.addEventListener("click", () => {  
  speak(txtMessage.value);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  padding: .5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
button {
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  background-color: #008cba;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<p>Текст для озвучки:</p>
<p>
  <textarea id="message">Привет! С вами «интерфейсы без шелухи» — заметки о продуктоводстве, интерфейсах, здравом смысле и разработке софта</textarea>
</p>
<button id="speak">Озвучить</button>
```